# what is the null space of a onto linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

i don't know if im conceptually understanding null space. For a one to one the only vector in the null space has to be zero.is that the case for an onto transformation?

Comment: Only when the dimensions of both spaces are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of a surjective linear transformation $T:V\to W$ can be any subspace of $V$ (if you are free to choose $W$ before stating what the kernel should be). The rank-nullity theorem sets some restrictions on the dimension of the kernel in terms of the dimensions of the domain and codomain vector spaces.

Comment: The question was about an onto linear transformation...

Comment: thanks @TalPorat (added the word 'surjective').

Answer (score 0):

For finite dimensional case just use the rank nullity theorem...